# DAG: interpretation difference of TOTAL and DIRECT effect in terms of adjusting

Tags: causality, confounding, adjustment, dag, causal-diagram

Could one explain in simple words how examining the total and direct effect differ in terms of adjusting? How to interpret the findings of these two approaches?

**DAG**

[image]

Minimal sufficient adjustment sets for estimating the TOTAL effect of comorbidity on mortality: **age**

Minimal sufficient adjustment sets for estimating the DIRECT effect of comorbidity on mortality:
**age, physical functioning**

Comment: Perhaps you can elaborate on what is confusing for you here. Comorbidity has a direct effect on mortality, but also an indirect effect through physical functioning. The total effect is the sum of these two. The idea is that being sick kills you. Being sick also lowers physical functioning, which can make it harder to take medication, go see the doctors or get exercise, which can also kill you. Older folks tend to be sicker and have lower physical functioning, but age also has its own effect on mortality. So age confounds both the direct and indirect effects when it is not adjusted for.

Comment: Confounds is a fancy way of saying that if we leave age out, comorbidity and functioning will "get credit" for the effect of age in addition to their own channel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The distinction between direct and total effect often concerns the role of **mediators**. In this DAG, we can try to discern "comorbidity" as the exposure of interest, and mortality as the response or outcome. "Age" fulfills the role of confounder, as it is causal of both comorbidity and mortality. Physical functioning is a mediator because it lies on the causal path from comorbidity to mortality. In any model, we would recommend adjustment for age to estimate the unconfounded effects of interest.

The regression estimate of the *direct* effect of comorbidity on mortality would adjust for physical functioning and age. The expected effect is an attenuation of the effect of comorbidity on mortality (relative to its total effect). Only the weight of the path leading from comorbidity to mortality is of interest.

The regression estimate of the *total* effect of comorbidity on mortality would adjust for age only. For the moment, ignore the effect of age-- Here not only the weight of the path leading directly from comorbidity to mortality of interest, but also the path from comorbidity to physical functioning and then to comorbidity is of interest. The entire (indirect) mediated paths have a weight given by the product of their respected paths. Now considering the adjustment for age, age confounds the effect between physical functioning and mortality, so the product from age to PF to mortality is subtracted from that indirect effect implicitly through adjustment.